# Overriding pre-commit hook or making somehow SVN happy

Tags: svn

I'm strugling with a problem which looks really weird for me.
I have checked out the trunk and then want to commit it to the another folder 
but I'm stumbled upon with the stuff called "pre-commit hook".
When I've tried to commit, I got this message:

> Commit failed (details follow): Commit blocked by pre-commit hook
>   (exit code 1) with output:
>   ***************************************************************  Only UTF-8 files can be committed for  .(sql|vbs|nsh|nsi)$ typ files.  You
>   tried to commit
>   product/trunk/somefile.sql,  please 
>   convert it to UTF-8. -- Thank you! :)
>   *************************************************************** If you want to break the lock, use the 'Check For Modifications' dialog or
>   the repository browser.

[image: screenshot]

The weird part is that, who those files became the part of repository if they are not intented to be there (however, this policy might be applied after those files became part of reposity?)

Do I need to follow those rules and convert ANSI -> UTF-8. 
I have even had a script in python which uses notepad++ API to convert files with required extensions to UTF-8? Is it the only way? Also, I don't know how many kind of pre-commit locks have repository? Because , I believe there is also a hook when posting exe files >2MB. So there might be a lot of hooks... And It can take days to achieve the goal to finally push source code to repo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot override the hook script from the client, so yes you will need to convert all of your files to UTF-8 just like the message says.

To find out what pre-commit hook scripts your repository has, you will have to ask your repository administrator. There are probably good reasons for what's been implemented.

> It can take days to achieve the goal to finally push source code to repo.

Your best solution is to not wring your hands over it, but instead learn what the rules are for committing to your repository and make sure that you've satisfied them all before committing. This will be much more efficient than poking at it and trying to figure out what you need to do to pass the pre-commit checks.

Comment: Well, at least, I have got that that message have been written by humans, and I need to convert it somehow. The question is also, will the working directory be after such manipulation at the same logical state as it was before forced UTF-8 conversion, however, converting from ANSI->UTF-8 is not lossy in theory, because, UTF is designed in such way that ANSI is the subset of UTF, so I can do it without any doubt, it should not break the integrity of the source code , I hope.

Comment: You have not answered the question: is it possible to override hook? Instead you are trying to like a small kid.  Remember, just knowing that you can physically kill people does not mean that tomorrow you will start killing people, I just wonder misintegrity concept that you can not push repo, however, you can pull such files. It is wrong, so maybe I want to contact administator and tell him to clean up repository from such files which are not eligible to be in repo? :)

Comment: No, I answered the question with the first 9 words of my answer. If there are non-UTF8 files in the repository, they were put there at a time when the hook script didn't exist, was disabled, or was broken. Any commit must adhere to the rules that exist at the time of committing, it's not retroactive.